# PHP instagram api -This client has not been approved to access this resource

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am using this https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

```
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;


Route::get('/', function () {



$instagram = new Instagram(array(
  'apiKey'      => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'apiSecret'   => 'xxxxxxxxx',
  'apiCallback' => 'http://mysite.co.uk'
));

$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$instagram->setAccessToken($token);
dd($instagram->getUserLikes());

});
```

I get a 400 error

```
{#191 ▼
  +"meta": {#190 ▼
    +"code": 400
    +"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException"
    +"error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."
  }
}
```

I am on localhost, how do I get around this? Do I have to add the url to Instagram?

http://192.168.10.10

Note : the access token is fine.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution to this?